# Cannot rename rosbag file after recording

Tags: c++, record, realsense

I would like to record a rosbag file with a specific name; however, I only know it after the recording is halfway done, so I cannot set the filename here:

```
cfg.enable_record_to_file("some/path/filename.bag");
```

I have tried to rename the new file as shown below without satisfactory success. I have also used std::experimental::filesystem::rename, with the same outcome. What did work was to record a second video (on the fly) and only then rename the first. This indicates that the (both) rename functions work, but I cannot change the filename it as it seems the file is still open in my current program.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    rs2::config cfg;
    rs2::device device;
    auto pipe = std::make_shared<rs2::pipeline>();

    cfg.disable_all_streams();
    cfg.enable_stream(RS2_STREAM_DEPTH, 640, 480, RS2_FORMAT_Z16, 30);

    cfg.enable_record_to_file("tmp.bag");
    pipe->start(cfg);
    device = pipe->get_active_profile().get_device();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    device.as<rs2::recorder>().pause();
    pipe->stop();

    int res = std::rename("tmp.bag", "test.bag");
    if (res == 0)
        std::cout << "File successfully renamed" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Error renaming file" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder how to 'unload' the produced video from the pipeline (pipe->stop() did not work), so I can rename the generated rosbag files on the fly.

Comment: Is this on Windows? If so, either your program or some other program has the file open I assume. Try this: Add a `{` before `rs2::config cfg;` and add a `}` after `pipe->stop();` to see if it's closed when all the `rs2` variables goes out of scope.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, this is Windows, but I don't see any reason why it would be different for other OS. In any case, I added curly brackets as suggested and this seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! The difference is that in Posix systems you'd be able to rename the file while it is open.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @TedLyngmo, adding curly brackets allowed me to change the filename on the fly. Code as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    {
        rs2::config cfg;
        rs2::device device;
        auto pipe = std::make_shared<rs2::pipeline>();

        cfg.disable_all_streams();
        cfg.enable_stream(RS2_STREAM_DEPTH, 640, 480, RS2_FORMAT_Z16, 30);

        cfg.enable_record_to_file("tmp.bag");
        pipe->start(cfg);
        device = pipe->get_active_profile().get_device();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        device.as<rs2::recorder>().pause();
        pipe->stop();
    }
    int res = std::rename("tmp.bag", "test.bag");
    if (res == 0)
        std::cout << "File successfully renamed" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Error renaming file" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I studied [rs-record-playback](https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/rs-record-playback) a bit more and the code below fixes the renaming issue.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    rs2::device device;
    auto pipe = std::make_shared<rs2::pipeline>();

    pipe->start();
    device = pipe->get_active_profile().get_device();

    if (!device.as<rs2::recorder>())
    {
        pipe->stop(); // Stop the pipeline with the default configuration
        pipe = std::make_shared<rs2::pipeline>();

        rs2::config cfg;
        cfg.disable_all_streams();
        cfg.enable_stream(RS2_STREAM_DEPTH, 640, 480, RS2_FORMAT_Z16, 30);
        cfg.enable_record_to_file("tmp.bag");

        pipe->start(cfg); 
        device = pipe->get_active_profile().get_device();
    }
    // record for 1 sec, if conditions can be added to check if recorder is initialised 
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    // if condition can be added to check if recording has been completed
    pipe->stop();
    pipe = std::make_shared<rs2::pipeline>(); // reset the shared pointer

    pipe->start();
    device = pipe->get_active_profile().get_device();

    int res = std::rename("tmp.bag", "testing.bag");
    if (res == 0)
        std::cout << "File successfully renamed" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Error renaming file" << std::endl;

    pipe->stop();
    pipe = std::make_shared<rs2::pipeline>();
}
```

Comment: Great, now you just need to figure out which one of the objects it is that kept the file open and see if there's a way to make it close the file without scoping that object out.